# With react , I am trying to add a section where it shows facts for 5 second intervals. No error shown, but the facts aren't appearing on the page

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, random

[Client side](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t5xB8.png)

On my react application, i am trying to add a section where it shows facts randomly for 5 second intervals. No error shown, but the facts aren't appearing on the page when I run my code.

```
import React from "react";
import "./leftbar.css"


class FactSlides extends React.Component {
  timerID;

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      factArr: ["a.", "b", "c", "d", "e"],
      abcFacts: "",
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.timerID = setInterval(() => {
      this.setState({
        abcFacts:
          this.state.factArr[
            Math.floor(Math.random() * this.state.factArr.length)
          ],
      });
    }, 5000);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    clearInterval(this.timerID);
  }
}
```

How is how I exported it in the leftbar component

```
export default function Leftbar(props) {
  return (
      <div className="leftbar">
        <div className="leftbarWrapper">
          <div className="leftBarTitle">
            Did you know?
          </div>
          <div className="space">
            &nbsp;
          </div>
          <div className="fact">
            <h2>{props.abcFacts}</h2>
          </div>
```

App.js

```
import React from 'react'
import Home from "./pages/home/Home";

function App() {
  return <Home/>
}

export default App;
```

Home.jsx where I am trying to render FactSlides

```
import React from "react";
import Navigationbar from "../../components/navigationbar/Navigationbar";
import Leftbar from "../../components/leftbar/Leftbar";
import Mainbar from "../../components/mainbar/Mainbar";
import Rightbar from "../../components/rightbar/Rightbar";
import FactSlides from "../../components/leftbar/Leftbar";
import "./home.css"

export default function Home() {
  return (
    <>
      <Navigationbar/>
      <div className="homeContainer">
        <Leftbar/>
        <Mainbar/>
        <Rightbar/>
        <FactSlides/>
      </div>
    </>
  )
    
}
```

Comment: If you don't return nothing from FactSlides, how are you passing those props to LeftBar ?

Comment: Can you upload how are you using the LeftBar component?

Not sure what is in the prop value

Answer (score 1):

The code from the question appears to be working as per the desired objective (once the `Leftbar` component was properly rendered within the `FactSlides` component). Please see below snippet for demo.

**Code Snippet**

```js
function Leftbar(props) {
  return (
    <div className="leftbar">
      <div className="leftbarWrapper">
        <div className="leftBarTitle">
          Did you know?
        </div>
        <div className="space">
          &nbsp;
        </div>
        <div class="fact">
          <h2>{props.abcFacts}</h2>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

class FactSlides extends React.Component {
  timerID;

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      factArr: ["a.", "b", "c", "d", "e"],
      abcFacts: "",
    };
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    this.timerID = setInterval(() => {
      this.setState({
        abcFacts:
          this.state.factArr[
            Math.floor(Math.random() * this.state.factArr.length)
          ],
      });
    }, 1500);
  };

  componentWillUnmount() {
    clearInterval(this.timerID);
  };
  
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Leftbar abcFacts={this.state.abcFacts} />
      </div>
    );
  };
};

ReactDOM.render(
  <div>
    DEMO
    <FactSlides />
  </div>,
  document.getElementById("rd")
);
```

```css
.fact{
    color: #3D1959;
    font-weight: lighter;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="rd" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you @jsN00b. Can I please have some clarification on where these lines "<div id="rd" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>" should be placed.

Comment: Those lines are required for adding a demo using stack-snippets (within stackoverflow). On your local, those may not be required. Please see [How to use stack snippets?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338537/) for more detailed information, if necessary. What is required is that this line: `<Leftbar abcFacts={this.state.abcFacts} />` is present within the `render() { return (); }` of `FactSlides` component.

Comment: Thanks for your help, however it is still not working and it states how the class 'FactSlides' is declared but never used.

Comment: Is there an `App.js` file on your project? If yes, within that please render `FactSlides` component (ie, add `<FactSlides />` within the `render()` method of `App.js`). If such a file is not present, please share the folder-structure so one of our SO-members may continue to assist further.

Comment: Thank you so much, I have edited showing my App.js file which I have, but I have not made with a render method

Comment: +1 for editing and updating the question. Thank you. Now, `App.js` returns this component: `<Home/>`. Is it possible to add `FactSlides` witin the `render()` function of `Home`?

Comment: Thank you so much for your patience, I have attempted to do so in home and have imported it, however it is just showing my previous screenshot of how it looks on the client side on the right side of the the web app

Comment: We're all here to help each other and learn. No problem. Now, the first line in `Home.jsx` is: `import FactSlides from "../../components/leftbar/Leftbar";`. Does the file `Leftbar` have any statement which does `export` the component `FactSlides`?

Comment: I have more import statements for home btw, I left them out as I thought it wouldn't be relevant, I have updated them in to the code now. The Leftbar has  the export default function Leftbar(props) function but it doesn't contain FactSlides to export. I tried writing "export default FactSlides;" but as that would be the second default export it is not working.

Comment: Okay, thank you. Which file contains the `FactSlides` class?

Comment: The Leftbar.jsx file. A snippet of Leftbar.jsx the code is provided under "How is how I exported it in the leftbar component" in my question.

Comment: Okay, so the same file `Leftbar.jsx` contains both `FactSlides` class and `Leftbar` function. Understood. Please see how one may use [named exports](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/export).

Comment: Thank for the useful documentation, I have read it an applied the export accordingly at the bottom of the Leftbar "export {FactSlides};" the code is running on the client side, but as the same it is now showing the contents of the array